# Concept: Using WCF Service VS. Sockets VS.?

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, service

We are developing an Client-Server-Scenario where the client application will be installed on hundred or thousands of clients.

We need the following:

- Client application (100-1000 clients)
- Administrator Console Application (10-50 administrators)
- WCF Service or TCP Socketserver or ? (other possibilities) that will interact with the client application, administrator console and
  a Microsoft SQL Server

  ```
  CLIENT -> SERVICE -> write information 2 DB

  CLIENT <- SERVICE -> read data records of DB

  CONSOLE <- SERVICE -> read data records of DB

  CONSOLE -> SERVICE -> write information 2 DB
  ```

So, what's the best solution for our scenario? Should we use a WCF Service, TCP Socketserver or something else? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Is this across the internet or do you have 100-1000 clients in your LAN? How many of those clients do you expect to be active simultaneously?

Comment: It's in our LAN. At least 30-40% are exptected to be active simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over all of the applications that will be communicating with your server application and can guarantee they will always run on Windows (as opposed to Mono), I would recommend WCF since it will handle most of the heavy lifting for you. If you're running .NET 4 then you can take advantage of the new [WCF Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782.aspx) functionality to reduce your administration headaches as well.

If you choose to use discovery though I'd recommend building in a service location cache as well though because 100-1000 UDP broadcasts over and over again could bring your network to its knees (and then you're network admin will blame you for network problems until the end of time).